# How to solve "Connection failed" for D1mini(ESP8266)

Tags: arduino, iot, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I'm trying to use D1 mini to fetch some data from website. I created an API key on Thingspeak ThingHttp. However, the client didn't connect properly. I got "connection failed" from the Serial monitor.

Here is my code. I think they are almost the same as [this](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/2.5.0/esp8266wifi/client-examples.html).

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
WiFiClientSecure client;

#define HOST "api.thingspeak.com"
void setup()
{
const char *ssid = "my_wifi";
const char *password = "qwertyui";
const char *API = "W0B96PD71W3Z245Q";
Serial.begin(115200);

WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
delay(100);
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
{
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
}
Serial.println("");
Serial.println("WiFi connected");
Serial.println("IP address: ");
IPAddress ip=WiFi.localIP();
Serial.println(ip);
delay(5000);
Serial.println("finish setup");
}
void loop()
{
delay(5000);
if (!client.connect(HOST, 80))
{
    Serial.println(F("Connection failed"));
    return;
}
Serial.println("***");
}
```

And here is what I got from the serial monitor.

```
WiFi connected
IP address: 
192.168.0.53
finish setup
Connection failed
Connection failed
```

It's obvious that it indeed connected to my wifi correctly, but just unable to connect to the server.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or are there any crucial step I should set on my D1mini?
(I'm using VSCode instead of Arduino IDE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong port number.

Port 80 is for unencrypted HTTP.

Port 443 is for HTTPS.

You're using `WiFiClientSecure`, so presumably you're intending to use HTTPS. HTTPS runs on port 443, not port 80. You'll need to change your code to use 443, or you'll need to use `WiFiClient` in order to work with port 80 (but make sure the API you're trying to connect to allows access over plain HTTP - most will not).

I highly recommend that you use an existing HTTP client rather than implement the protocol yourself as you'll need to with `WiFiClient` or `WiFiClientSecure`, which just provide TCP and encrypted TCP connections. You can find [examples of how to use `ESP8266HTTPClient` in the ESP8266 Arduino core repository](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/examples).